# modelsummary display output from lm and brms concurrently with statistics

Tags: r, lm, modelsummary, brms

```
models <- list(
"Linear" = lm(outcome ~ week * food data = df ),
"Bayesian" = brm(outcome ~ s(week, k = 4, fx = TRUE, by = food) + food, data = df, family = "zero_one_inflated_beta")
)
```

The following code works when I run it

```
modelsummary(models,
             estimate = "{estimate}[{conf.low}, {conf.high}]",
             statistic = NULL)
```

The problem is that when I attempt to also get the p-value, t-value and standard error of the linear model with the following code, the error comes up as `Error: std.error is not available. The estimate and statistic arguments must correspond to column names in the output of this command: get_estimates(model)`

```
modelsummary(models,
             estimate = "estimate[{conf.low}, {conf.high}]",
             statistic = c("Std.Error" = "std.error", 
                           "t-value" = "statistic", 
                           "p-value" = "p.value"))
```

How can I enable modelsummary() to ignore the display of statistics when there is none like in the case of the `brms` model instead of throwing an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common use-case which is not well supported in the CRAN version of `modelsummary`. Instead of suggesting a complicated hack, I pushed a change to the development version which makes this much easier. You can install it now with:

```r
remotes::install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")
```

Restart `R` completely for the changes to take effect.

Then, you can do things like:

```r
library(brms)
library(modelsummary)

mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp + qsec, data = mtcars)
mod2 <- brm(mpg ~ hp + qsec, data = mtcars)
models <- list(mod1, mod2)

modelsummary(
    models,
    statistic = c("std.error", "conf.int"),
    # clean-up coefficient names
    coef_rename = \(x) gsub("b_", "", x),
    coef_omit = "Intercept")
```

|  | (1) | (2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hp | -0.085 | -0.084 |
|  | (0.014) |  |
|  | [-0.113, -0.056] | [-0.112, -0.055] |
| qsec | -0.887 | -0.867 |
|  | (0.535) |  |
|  | [-1.980, 0.207] | [-1.944, 0.239] |
| sigma |  | 3.815 |
|  |  | [3.000, 4.991] |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 |
| R2 | 0.637 | 0.631 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.612 | 0.553 |
| AIC | 180.3 |  |
| BIC | 186.2 |  |
| Log.Lik. | -86.170 |  |
| F | 25.431 |  |
| ELPD |  | -91.1 |
| ELPD s.e. |  | 4.9 |
| LOOIC |  | 182.3 |
| LOOIC s.e. |  | 9.8 |
| WAIC |  | 181.9 |
| RMSE | 3.57 | 3.57 |